# Multiple Datatables in R using DT Package

Tags: r, datatables

I am trying to save 2 datatables to a html page using Rstudio with the package dt (datatables)
I can do this fine with 1 datatable but I cant do it with 2

```
#Example I know this is duplicated but for test purposes
if(require(DT)==FALSE){install.packages("DT",repos="http://cran.r-project.org")}
require(DT)
tsta=datatable(iris)
tstb=datatable(iris)
saveWidget(tsta & tstb, 'foo.html')
#saveWidget(tsta, 'foo.html')
```

This does not work but how can I show the datatables either side by side or below each other.

Comment: You can try it with RMarkdown. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46206021/how-to-export-two-html-widgets-in-the-same-html-page-in-r) can help.